# How to have dd(data definition) in jQuery automatically close when a user clicks on another dt (definition term)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an accordion using the structure of dl, dt and dd. (Definition list). The logic is that if the user clicks on dt (definition term), the dd (data definition) will expand to display. In my style sheet, I have created a class style of (.open) which shows me an image using CSS Sprites.

My Codes look like this :

```
 $("dd").hide();
 $("dt").click(function(e) {
$(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle();
}
```

The problem is that If I click on another dt, this existing dd should be able to collapse (toggle back) and the existing dt has to remove the class "open".

How is that possible?

Thanks!
James

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate issue?

Comment: Share proper code, I mean Javascript, css and html.

Comment: can you please share your html and css code fro more clarification

Comment: Please click the `<>` button in the editor and create a [mcve] - you likely want to do something like `$(this).siblings().removeClass("open")`

Comment: https://codepen.io/vsalda/pen/KHBzs

Answer (score 0):

So sorry that my question posted is not very clear. My codes are shown at the bottom.

```js
$("document").ready(function(e) {
    $("dd").hide();
    $("dt").click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle();
    });
    });
```

```css
dt {
color: #268bd2;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
background: url(../_images/arrow-sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
line-height: 16px;
}

dt:hover {
 background-position: 0 -16px;
color: #2aa198;
}

dt.open {
background-position: 0 -32px;
}

dt.open:hover {
background-position: 0 -48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<dl>
<dt><h3>How do I get notified?</h3></dt>

<dd><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean auctor vulputate luctus. Cras tincidunt turpis vitae neque placerat, vel imperdiet neque varius. Sed molestie gravida magna sit amet convallis. Cras vestibulum blandit imperdiet. Nam sagittis elementum lectus eget euismod. Morbi vel lacus dui. Aliquam hendrerit leo eu arcu tincidunt, a venenatis est tincidunt. Nunc quis lectus in massa aliquam aliquam et eget dui. Aenean efficitur maximus placerat. </p></dd>

<dt>
  <h3>How do I use the Tour Vouchers?</h3></dt>

<dd><p>Nunc tincidunt imperdiet ligula, vitae auctor massa tristique ut. Sed vulputate, diam eu lacinia sodales, mauris magna egestas nunc, a ornare arcu purus non quam. Pellentesque et ex purus. Nulla sagittis urna ipsum, quis interdum augue tristique sit amet. Duis nec aliquam nisl. Nunc elementum hendrerit turpis dapibus bibendum. Fusce convallis leo sed porttitor euismod. Cras imperdiet lorem nec turpis cursus, quis lobortis augue tempus. Etiam tempor quis quam nec euismod. Maecenas et dictum diam, eget elementum tellus. Sed at sagittis massa. Nunc porttitor justo non nisl vulputate, vitae congue erat suscipit. Aliquam malesuada ultrices arcu at aliquet. Maecenas consectetur, quam a malesuada volutpat, urna augue fermentum neque, vel pharetra dolor tellus ut felis. </p></dd>

</dl>
</body>
```

So If I click on another dt, the existing dd should be able to collapse (toggle back) and the existing dt has to remove the class "open". Something like what you see for the accordion in jQuery UI.

I can't seem to wrap my head around ;(

Thanks for all your assistance!

Cheers!
James

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".dt").click(function(e) {
  $(".dt").removeClass("open");
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.open {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dt">div1</div>
<div class="dt">div2</div>
<div class="dt">div3</div>
```

This is simple but is that what you wanna do

Comment: He has `<dl><dt></dt><dd></dd>...</dl>`

Comment: OK, i this is a sample. then what he wanna do is the same?. do not understand this downgrade

Comment: He does not use divs!

Comment: `div` `dt` `dd` just the tag. OK you can change it if you wanna do?

Comment: The structure is completely different - children and siblings etc

Comment: what i want to say is: he want to remove other `open` class then add for a single ones!

Comment: You do not handle `this existing dd should be able to collapse`

Comment: Also I think my comment is more relevant since it only removes the class from the siblings